# Why did Shiva cut off an elephant's head in violation of Ahimsa?

Tags: shiva, animals, sacrifice

If animal killing is not good, then why did Lord Shiva cut off an elephant's head for his son Ganesha? Does that mean we may kill animals for our own means as our Lord did?

Comment: Elephant's head became His son's head. Can we do that? Btw, some stories say Shiva granted the boon to Gajasura.

Comment: What kind of boon(Killed an animal)?

Comment: Do you want the answer of "Is animal killing prohibited in Hinduism" OR explanation of Lord Shiva replacing elephant's head for his son Ganesha ?

Comment: Gajasura did tapasya of Lord Shiva and asked to be smartest or most intelligent of all in all three worlds (loks) as a boon. This was not possible with his current body coz that body of him can't carry that level of intelligence. So shiva asked him to wait for some time, you will get your boon soon. Then the Elephant's (Gajasura) head placed on Ganesha's body so that Lord Shiva can make his boon fulfill by making him smartest in all three worlds. It was leela of Shiva. And Elephant gave his head wililngly coz he knew that Shiva is going to fulfill his boon by this way.

Comment: Lord Shiva is Bhagawan. If he kills someone that being will get Moksha. But if u kill someone then probably both u and the being u killed will go downwards. So, think before u leap. Don't get the wrong moral out of the story :D

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Wikipedia:

" Shiva, having cooled down by this time, agreed to Parvati’s conditions. He sent his Shiva-dutas out with orders to bring back the head of the first creature that is lying dead with its head facing North. The Shiva-dutas soon returned with the head of a strong and powerful elephant Gajasura which Lord Brahma placed onto boy's body. Breathing new life into him, he was declared as Gajanana and gave him the status of being foremost among the gods, and leader of all the ganas (classes of beings), Ganapati.   "

Here this is saying head of a lying dead creature.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No killing was done there if  it was a dead elephants head. And i don't know what actually happened that time if something like that ever happened.